# Pandas - Python 2.7: How convert timeseries index to seconds of the day?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to convert a time series index to a seconds of the day i.e. so that the seconds increases from 0-86399 as the day progresses.  I currently can recover the time of the day, but am having trouble converting this to seconds in a vectorized way:

```
df['timeofday'] = df.index.time
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Jeff points out my original answer misunderstood what you were doing. But the following should work and it is vectorized. My answer relies on numpy `datetime64` operations (subtract the beginning of the day from the current `datetime64` and the divide through with a `timedelta64` to get seconds):

```
>>> df

                            A
2011-01-01 00:00:00 -0.112448
2011-01-01 01:00:00  1.006958
2011-01-01 02:00:00 -0.056194
2011-01-01 03:00:00  0.777821
2011-01-01 04:00:00 -0.552584
2011-01-01 05:00:00  0.156198
2011-01-01 06:00:00  0.848857
2011-01-01 07:00:00  0.248990
2011-01-01 08:00:00  0.524785
2011-01-01 09:00:00  1.510011
2011-01-01 10:00:00 -0.332266
2011-01-01 11:00:00 -0.909849
2011-01-01 12:00:00 -1.275335
2011-01-01 13:00:00  1.361837
2011-01-01 14:00:00  1.924534
2011-01-01 15:00:00  0.618478

df['sec'] = (df.index.values
            - df.index.values.astype('datetime64[D]'))/np.timedelta64(1,'s')

                            A      sec
2011-01-01 00:00:00 -0.112448        0
2011-01-01 01:00:00  1.006958     3600
2011-01-01 02:00:00 -0.056194     7200
2011-01-01 03:00:00  0.777821    10800
2011-01-01 04:00:00 -0.552584    14400
2011-01-01 05:00:00  0.156198    18000
2011-01-01 06:00:00  0.848857    21600
2011-01-01 07:00:00  0.248990    25200
2011-01-01 08:00:00  0.524785    28800
2011-01-01 09:00:00  1.510011    32400
2011-01-01 10:00:00 -0.332266    36000
2011-01-01 11:00:00 -0.909849    39600
2011-01-01 12:00:00 -1.275335    43200
2011-01-01 13:00:00  1.361837    46800
2011-01-01 14:00:00  1.924534    50400
2011-01-01 15:00:00  0.618478    54000
```

Comment: this will give u the second portion of the Timestamp now seconds since the beginning of the day - u need to subtract a normalized date then convert to seconds

Comment: You're right @Jeff, I misunderstood the question. I fixed my answer but it is not particularly elegant.

Answer (score 3):

May be a bit overdone, but this would be my answer:

```
from pandas import date_range, Series, to_datetime

# Some test data
rng = date_range('1/1/2011 01:01:01', periods=3, freq='s')
df = Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng).to_frame()

def sec_in_day(timestamp):
    date = timestamp.date() # We get the date less the time
    elapsed_time = timestamp.to_datetime() - to_datetime(date) # We get the time
    return elapsed_time.total_seconds()

Series(df.index).apply(sec_in_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified KarlD's answer for datetime with time zone:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"t_naive":pd.date_range("20160101","20160102", freq = "2H")})
d['t_utc'] = d['t_naive'].dt.tz_localize("UTC")
d['t_ct'] = d['t_utc'].dt.tz_convert("America/Chicago")

print(d.head())
              # t_naive                     t_utc                      t_ct
# 0 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 2015-12-31 18:00:00-06:00
# 1 2016-01-01 02:00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00+00:00 2015-12-31 20:00:00-06:00
# 2 2016-01-01 04:00:00 2016-01-01 04:00:00+00:00 2015-12-31 22:00:00-06:00
# 3 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00+00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00-06:00
# 4 2016-01-01 08:00:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00+00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00-06:00
```

The answer by KarlD gives sec of day in UTC

```
s0 = (d["t_naive"].values - d["t_naive"].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))/np.timedelta64(1,'s')
s0
# array([     0.,   7200.,  14400.,  21600.,  28800.,  36000.,  43200.,
        # 50400.,  57600.,  64800.,  72000.,  79200.,      0.])

s1 = (d["t_ct"].values - d["t_ct"].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))/np.timedelta64(1,'s')
s1
# array([     0.,   7200.,  14400.,  21600.,  28800.,  36000.,  43200.,
        # 50400.,  57600.,  64800.,  72000.,  79200.,      0.])
```

For sec of day in local time, use:

```
s2 = (d["t_ct"].view("int64") - d["t_ct"].dt.normalize().view("int64"))//pd.Timedelta(1, unit='s')
#use d.index.normalize() for index
s2.values
# array([64800, 72000, 79200,     0,  7200, 14400, 21600, 28800, 36000,
       # 43200, 50400, 57600, 64800], dtype=int64)
```

or,

```
s3 = d["t_ct"].dt.hour*60*60 + d["t_ct"].dt.minute*60+ d["t_ct"].dt.second
s3.values
# array([64800, 72000, 79200,     0,  7200, 14400, 21600, 28800, 36000,
       # 43200, 50400, 57600, 64800], dtype=int64)
```